# What is an electrified channel?

Tags: electricity, terminology

I've been asked to create a sketch of an electrified channel. I've never heard of this terminology before. I tried to Google it and it came up with either guitar related answers, or a few about circuits.

Edit for clarification:
A professor asked me in regards to a sorting apparatus. The project has to do with sorting colloids in a liquid. Possibly by zeta potential. That's what we're in the process of figuring out.

Edit:
I figured it out. It's more of a name given by some graduate students. It took a lot of digging, but I finally found it in a paper written in the lab. It's just what they called the method with which they sorted the colloids. I'm unsure if I can go into detail as I'm unsure if it's sensitive information, so I'll just leave it there. This is why I decided to do an edit over an answer.

Comment: Who asked? what have they shown you so far?

Comment: In what context? Semiconductor device? Gas switch?

Comment: A professor asked me in regards to a sorting apparatus. The project has to do with sorting colloids in a liquid. Possibly by zeta potential. That's what we're in the process of figuring out.

Comment: @abyssmu, please include all relevant information in the question, since comments might be cleaned up by the mods.